# Anything wrong with modify an object inside a loop?

Tags: java

```
public Collection<QueueMetrics> getAllGatewayQueueMetricsCurrent(String keywords)
{
    QueueMetrics qmInput = null;
    QueueMetrics qmImport = null ;
    QueueMetrics qmReport = null ;
    ArrayList<QueueMetrics> metrics = new ArrayList<QueueMetrics>();

    for (String keyword : keywords.split(",")){
        ConsoleServiceMBean console = getConsoleService(keyword);
        populateMessageCountStr(qmInput, keyword, console, "input");
        populateMessageCountStr(qmImport, keyword, console, "import");
        populateMessageCountStr(qmReport, keyword, console, "report");
    }
    metrics.add(qmInput);
    metrics.add(qmImport);
    metrics.add(qmReport);

    return metrics;
}

private void populateMessageCountStr(QueueMetrics qMetrics, String keyword, ConsoleServiceMBean console, String type)
{
    QueueMetrics tempMetric = console.getGatewayQueueMetricsCurrent(type, keyword);
            if( qMetrics == null ){
             qMetrics = tempMetric ;
    }else{
        qMetrics.setPendingMessageCountStr( qMetrics.getPendingMessageCountStr() + ", " + tempMetric.getPendingMessageCount());
         }

}
```

I tried to update qmInput, qmImport and qmReport inside the upper for loop, by calling the populateMessageCountStr and passing in the object itself to be updated. In next loop, the same object will be updated one more time with additional data. However, the end result of this program is that qmInput, qmImport and qmReport are all null. Anybody knows why? To provide more info, when I change the upper function a little bit:

```
        qmInput = populateMessageCountStr(qmInput, keyword, console, "input");
        qmImport = populateMessageCountStr(qmImport, keyword, console, "import");
        qmReport = populateMessageCountStr(qmReport, keyword, console, "report");
```

and the lower function returns the updated QueueMetrics instead of void. The program works as expcected. Anybody knows why the original way didn't work? I appreciate any useful comments.

Comment: The `populateMessageCountStr(...)` method returns `void`. How can you use it in an assignment statement?

Comment: Modifying a parameter does not modify the parameter value as seen by the caller.  (But note carefully: Modifying an object addressed by a passed reference parameter *will* modify the same object as seen by the caller.)

Answer (score 2):

> However, the end result of this program is that qmInput, qmImport and qmReport are all null.

Because, you are re-assigning the passed `QueueMetrics` reference in that method to a new object if it is equal to `null`, which it will be on the first invocation. In which case the original reference will still point to `null`. And hence it will remain `null` on all the further invocation of that method, as the condition `qMetrics == null` will always be *true*.

Since Java passes the reference by Value, re-assigning the `qMetrics` to a different instance, will change the value of the copy of the reference that is passed. But it will not modify the reference value of the original reference.

To solve the issue, simply return the modified reference from the method (change the return type of `populateMessageCounterStr()` to `QueueMetrics`, and assign it to the original reference on the calling side.

Comment: +1. Methods with side-effects on the passed arguments are terrible anyway.

Answer (score 0):

qMetrics is set locally and reference to it is lost. so caller of method  `populateMessageCountStr` will not get to see the reference to it unless you return that reference.

```
if( qMetrics == null ){
             qMetrics = tempMetric ;
```

when changed it to

```
qmInput = populateMessageCountStr
```

and additionally  change return type and `return qMetrics`  in `populateMessageCountStr`

In first iteration when `qMetrics` is null new instance gets created `console.getGatewayQueue...` (and assuming it does not return null) `qMetrics` reference is returned and stored in `qmInput` and same is passed to `populateMessageCountStr` in subsequent iteration.

Answer (score 0):

In java:

```
Object a = null;
Object b = a;
b = "foo";
```

leaves a null, which is your problem.
What you want to do is:

```
Object a = <something>;
Object b = a;
b.mutate();
```

This is safe as b.mutate is mutating < something >, so effectively a.mutate() and b.mutate() are equivalent.